# Is there a good replacement for the Force Wrench in Monster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

One of my staple items in FTB Unleashed was the Force Wrench. For those who don't know, it allowed you to pickup items without loosing their contents. (Chests would still have their inventory, tanks would keep their fuel, and you could move spawners.)

FTB Monster doesn't include the Dartcraft mod, and so that item is not available. Is there another item in the mod that behaves in a similar way? My two primary use cases are.

1. Being able to move a chest without having it drop it's contents
2. Moving mob spawners

I am OK if I have to use a different item for each task.

Comment: Gravity gun does the trick.

Comment: Some thaumcraft thaumic tinkerer wand focus should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Dolly](http://ftbwiki.org/Dolly) from JABBA to move vanilla chests, chests from Iron Chests, BC Tanks and machines Thermal Expansion and IC2. Be careful as it can't move Factorization Barrels, or Better Storage Chests. It's a good tool for reorienting said blocks.

When you have a filled dolly in your inventory you receive some penalty (slowness and mining fatigue iirc), but you can avoid it by putting the dolly in a backpack. This effect doesn't stack.

If you upgrade it with 3 diamons you get the [Diamond Dolly](http://wiki.skcraft.com/jabba/diamond-dolly), which can move spawners but only six times. This is the only tool to my knowledge that lets you transport a spawner across dimensions.

EDIT: Apparently you can use a Bedrock Pickaxe from RotaryCraft to retrieve vanilla spawners too. It takes no damage from doing that, but it's a very endgame item.

Answer (score 1):

Thaumcraft addon "Thaumic Tinkerer" offers the dislocation focus, which will transport Monster Spawners at 100 Ordo, Perditio, and 20 Aer Vis cost

Answer (score 1):

MFR Portaspawner? Those move spawners, but yes, bedrock pick is better as rc bedrock Pick has infinite durability but Portaspawner works once only and you have to wait 30 seconds after picking it up before putting it down.

Answer (score 0):

I would think a translocator from Blood Magic would work.
However, that is an block not an item